# How to set TextView inside custom ImageButton (FAB)?

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

I am trying to build an app using the new material design specs.
I am currently trying to get a cusdtom FAB layout working, similar to the one in the new Inbox app.
I have one main button, which when clicked, expands to several smaller ones.
However i want to add a textview to the left of the smaller buttons, like the inbox app.

I cant seem to find a way of doing this.
The floating action button i am using is based off this library, but with a few modifications https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/README.md

If someone could suggest a way of doing this, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Corey :)